# Next.js suddenly not importing any packages

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, yarnpkg

After writing some seemingly irrelevant code, my project has stopped working altogether and I am getting "Cannot find package" errors for seemingly every package.

For example, this error I am getting after the code was working fine:

```
error - Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'react-hook-form' imported from /Users/~/dev/podcast/.next/server/pages/create.js
Did you mean to import react-hook-form-virtual-91dc5e5cb0/0/cache/react-hook-form-npm-7.22.1-0f35fbb533-52e0187503.zip/node_modules/react-hook-form/dist/index.cjs.js?
```

I have tried removing my node_modules and yarn.lock then reinstalling with `yarn install` to no avail.

My guess is that I may have broken something in my package.json or other configuration files since now it is suggesting to import from node_modules instead?

Node v16.13.0
React v17.0.2
Yarn v3.1.1

Comment: Remove `.yarn`, `.yarnrc.yml`, `yarn.lock`, `node_modules`, `.next`. Then run `yarn version set stable` followed by `yarn install`. Try running `yarn next dev`. If the error is still persistent, post the complete error logs with your `package.json`. Note that Next.js v12.0.5 and above are broken on yarn pnp. If you have put latest in `package.json` for `next`, then change it to `12.0.4`.

Comment: @brc-dd Thank you, that seems to have worked for me!